# Convert numpy array in column vector

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python programming so excuse me if the question may seem silly or trivial.

So for a certain function I need to do a check in case `x` is a vector and (in that case) it must be a column vector. However I wanted to make it so that the user could also pass it a row vector and turn it into a column vector.

However at this point how do I make it not do the check if `x` is a scalar quantity.

I attach a code sketch to illustrate the problem.  Thanks in advance to whoever responds

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(80, 130, 10)
# x: float = 80.0
print('array before:\n', x)

if x is not np.array:
    x = np.array(x).reshape([len(x), 1])

print('array after:\n', x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the type using `if not isinstance(x, np.ndarray)`.  After that check you can check the number of dimension of the array and convert to a columnar array.

In the code below, first `if` block checks and converts to an array.  Then we get how many dimensions are missing.  I.e. a scalar value is missing 2 dimensions, a flat list is missing 1 dimension.  Finally we iterate over the number of missing dimensions up-converting the array's dimensions with each step.

```py
def to_column_array(x):
    if not isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        x = np.array(x)

    missing_dims = 2 - x.ndim
    if missing_dims < 0:
        raise ValueError('You array has too many dimensions')

    for _ in range(missing_dims):
        x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
    return x
```

So if a user has just a number, this convert it to an array of size (1, 1).

```py
to_column_array(10)
# returns:
array([[10]])
```

Passing in a list or list of lists converts to an array as well.

```
to_column_array([3, 6, 9])
# returns:
array([[3],
       [6],
       [9]])

to_column_array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])
# returns:
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 1):

'vector', 'row vector', 'column vector' are not normal `numpy` terms.  `numpy` has arrays, which can have any dimension, 0, 1, 2 etc.  It's more general than typical linear algebra, where everything is 2d, either a matrix or row/column vector.  `numpy` can have the same shapes, but it isn't restricted to them.

Let's make several variables:

```
In [241]: x = np.arange(80, 130, 10); y = 80.0; z = [1,2,3]

In [242]: x,y,z
Out[242]: (array([ 80,  90, 100, 110, 120]), 80.0, [1, 2, 3])
```

`x` is an array, and so has a `shape`.  `z` is list, so only has `len` (basic python).  `y` is scalar, so has neither.

```
In [243]: x.shape
Out[243]: (5,)    
In [244]: len(z)
Out[244]: 3
```

The `(5,)` shape `x` can be `reshape` to (5,1).  A common idiom to do that is indexing:

```
In [245]: x[:,None]
Out[245]: 
array([[ 80],
       [ 90],
       [100],
       [110],
       [120]])    
In [246]: _.shape
Out[246]: (5, 1)
```

We can test for class with `isinstance`:

```
In [247]: isinstance(x,np.ndarray)
Out[247]: True    
In [248]: isinstance(z,np.ndarray)
Out[248]: False
```

The list can be turned into an array, and even given an extra leading dimension:

```
In [249]: np.array(z)
Out[249]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [251]: np.array(z)[None,:]
Out[251]: array([[1, 2, 3]])    
In [252]: _.shape
Out[252]: (1, 3)
```

So arrays with shape (5,),(1,5), and (5,1) can all have the same numbers, and be reshaped to one another.  In many ways they are the same, but there are differences when it comes to how they interact with other arrays.  By the rules of `broadcasting` the (5,) shape is more like (1,5).  That's an important topic, but I won't get into that here.

The scalar can also be made into an array, but the shape will be (), 0d.

```
In [253]: np.array(y)
Out[253]: array(80.)    
In [254]: _.shape
Out[254]: ()
```

`np.array` takes an `ndmin` parameter that can ensure that the result has at least n dimensions:

```
In [255]: np.array(y, ndmin=2)
Out[255]: array([[80.]])    
In [256]: np.array(x, ndmin=2)
Out[256]: array([[ 80,  90, 100, 110, 120]])    
In [257]: np.array(z, ndmin=2)
Out[257]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

There's a set of `atleast` functions that do the same thing

```
In [259]: np.atleast_2d(z)
Out[259]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Ensuring anything is a column vector requires at bit more fiddling, such as a reshape or `transpose`.

```
In [260]: np.atleast_2d(z).T
Out[260]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Note that transpose of a 1d array does not change it.  `transpose` does not add dimensions:

```
In [261]: x.T
Out[261]: array([ 80,  90, 100, 110, 120])
```

The list display of these arrays reflects the dimensions.  Just count the [].

So there are various ways of ensuring the variable is an "vector", even a "column vector".  But you should be clear, for your own understanding, as to why it needs to be this way.  The more comon 1d shape of an array may be just as useful.

Comment: @hpauli I thank you for your comprehensive response. I am well aware that the terms vector, row vector and column vector are terms peculiar to linear algebra rather than programming. But I intentionally used these terms to immediately highlight the goal I wanted to get to